# passing array to php from android fails on android 4.1 but succeeds on android 5+

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays

Note : the below code work perfectly with my galaxy s5 with android 5.0, however it seems to always fail to save when using my galaxy s3 with android 4.1. all other parts of my application works well on both phones.

This is how i'm filling the JSArray, all the data has been checked and is all valid with no null values.

```
 int i = 0;
                while (i<StudentIDzArray.length)
                {
                    //InsertMarks(getApplicationContext(), StudentIDzArray[i], SubjectID, SubjectName, StudentMarksArrayTemp[i], ClassID, ClassName, ExamNumber, StudentsArray[i]);
                    String SingleStudentInfo[] = {StudentIDzArray[i], SubjectID, SubjectName, StudentMarksArrayTemp[i], ClassID, ClassName, ExamNumber, StudentsArray[i]};
                    AllStudentInfo.add(SingleStudentInfo);
                    i++;
                }

                jsArray = new JSONArray(AllStudentInfo);
```

defining the json array as global variable

```
JSONArray jsArray;
```

Using this function to to save data to mysql database using Volley Library

```
 public void InsertMarks(final Context context)
    {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,SaveUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response)
            {
                if(response.equals("success"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Success added " ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Failure to add"+  response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,"connection error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams()
            {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("StudentsData",jsArray.toString());

                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(sr);
    }
```

and this is the php code for reading the array and getting all values to be able so save to mysql.

```
$AllStudentsData =$_POST['StudentsData'];
$AllObj = json_decode($AllStudentsData);

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("****","*****","********","*****") or die ( mysqli_error($MySQL_Handle) ); 

$sSQL= 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8'; 
mysqli_query($con,$sSQL) or die ('Can\'t charset in DataBase'); 

mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8;");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET utf8;");

$ww = 0;

while ($ww < count($AllObj))
{
$StudentID = $AllObj[$ww][0];
$SubjectID = $AllObj[$ww][1];
$SubjectName = $AllObj[$ww][2];
$Mark = $AllObj[$ww][3];
$ClassNo = $AllObj[$ww][4];
$ClassName = $AllObj[$ww][5];
$Exam_ID = $AllObj[$ww][6];
$StudentFullName = $AllObj[$ww][7];

if($Exam_ID=="0")
{
$result1 = mysql_query("select * from  Student_Marks where Student_No='$StudentID' AND Subject_No='$SubjectID'");

if(mysql_num_rows($result1)>0)
{
$result = mysql_query("update Student_Marks SET 
S1_Mark_1A ='$Mark'
where Student_No='$StudentID' AND Subject_No='$SubjectID' AND ClassID='$ClassNo' ");
}
else
{
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Student_Marks (Student_No,StudentFullName,Subject_No,Subject_Name,S1_Mark_1A,ClassID,ClassName) 
VALUES
('".$StudentID."','".$StudentFullName."','".$SubjectID."','".$SubjectName."','".$Mark."','".$ClassNo."','".$ClassName."')");
}
}
```

after some work done trying to figure out what goes wrong and where, seems that the data becomes rubbish when using JSONArray.toString on the android 4, and stays good on the android 5.

```
params.put("StudentsData",jsArray.toString());
```

Does this code gets different compiling on java on both android 5 and android 4 ?

Comment: `trying to pass an array into the php page`. What kind of array?  You could explain your code first. Also show your php script.

Comment: i have edited the code, hope it's clearer what i mean

Comment: You still did not tell what/where does not work.

Comment: just edited my question to include the results i found . hope it clears the problem now

Comment: If you want that this takes still more time you should continue giving not to the point info. What are you sending with `jsArray.toString());` with both Androids? And what are yout receiving inthe php script then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems that .toString gets the right outcome on android 5.0 ... however on the android 4+, it gets the array messed up, have no idea why.

what i did to fix it was download the gson library, import it to my project and used the following code

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.tojson(myarray);
```

instead of

```
myarray.toString();
```

then the application worked fine on all android versions supported by the application which was android 4+.